# Why are search results in MediaWiki displaying without formatting?

Tags: mediawiki

I installed MediaWiki and I noticed that the search results are not being formatted, This means, if I have an article which contains the following text:

```
'''This is a test'''
```

This will show up in bold when you are viewing the actual article but when you search for example: test, the search results will be displayed without the formatting and will be displayed with the full code, which means that in the search results, this is what is shown:

```
Article Name
      '''This is a test'''
```

I obviously want it to look like this:

```
Article Name
      This is a test
```

I didn't modify any of the code in MediaWiki yet. How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: I *think* that's by design.  If the text was formatted you may not be able to clearly see what a particular search result was found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of MediaWiki are you using?

You may need to install the MWSearch extension to get the results without the formatting.
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MWSearch

Answer (score 2):

As of now MWSearch has been replaced by Cirrus:
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CirrusSearch

While SphinxSearch is more recommended for smaller sites (compared to Wikipedia):
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SphinxSearch